# running java jar from php exec or shell_exec isnt working for batik

Tags: java, php, iis-7, exec

I am trying to do

```
exec(java -jar "C:\batik\batik-rasterizer.jar" -m image/png -d 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg");
```

it's not giving me any results can anybody suggest what am i doing wrong.

machine is windows 2008 R2 enterprise
iis 7
with fastcgi

exec('java -version')

Comment: Is the Java executable somewhere in your path? Does the user account your script's running under have access rights to the java directory and execute permissions on java.exe?

Comment: @Marc, java perms does not need Execute permissions as its the systems kernel so it should have access other than UAC for out of location access, and java should add its self to the list of paths for runing without full path E.G echo in CMD can be called from path but its saved in %SysDrive%/windows/system32/

Comment: @Barker: yes, but the IIS user has limited privileges by default and has to be explicitly granted exec permissions on most everything. As well, it's not a system kernel call that the OP is doing. He's using an exec call in PHP to a command line .exe.

Comment: @Marc (IIS info is new) and yes your right if using IIS.
@sushil find the java.exe application, rightclick on it then click on security / permissions tab, add the IIS user to the application and set its execute to allow then you might have to do some thing in IIS but marc seems to know more (iis and php are not the best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your computer have UAC turned off? (Windows 7 or Vista, accessing C: with out UAC perms will error so for ease turn it off),

Secondly, exec requires a string input,

Thirdly \ need to be escaped as Phill said

```
exec('java -jar "C:/batik/batik-rasterizer.jar" -m C:/pathto/image/png -d 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg"');
```

**UPDATED FOR COMMENT ON PHILLS**

Check that your allowed to use exec/system/backticks, using the CLI

1. Create a php file with `<?php exec("echo hello"); ?>` inside it save it
2. Then start CMD,
3. open a new window (open up my/ computer) and browse to your php.exe application
4. copy the address of the folder where you found it
5. in cmd type "cd " without quotes and after that right click and click pase then hit enter
6. type "php " (again without quotes) drag php file saved to the cmd box and drop it
7. then hit enter and see if it says hello in the cmd box

if this does not work check java is working without path to exe, in the cmd windows type your `java --help` and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the path forward and back slashes

```
exec(java -jar "C:\batik\batik-rasterizer.jar" -m image/png -d 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg");
```

might try forward slash:

```
exec('java -jar "C:/batik/batik-rasterizer.jar" -m image/png -d 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg"');
```

or forward slash w/ param path as well:

```
exec('java -jar "C:/batik/batik-rasterizer.jar" -m C:/pathto/image/png -d 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:/pathtoimg/temp/2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg"');
```

UPDATE sorry i think it's backslash

might try back slash:

```
exec('java -jar "C:\batik\batik-rasterizer.jar" -m image\png -d 
"C:\pathtoimg\temp\2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:\pathtoimg\temp\2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg"');
```

or back slash w/ param path as well:

```
exec('java -jar "C:\batik\batik-rasterizer.jar" -m C:\pathto\image\png -d 
"C:\pathtoimg\temp\2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.png" -w 800 
"C:\pathtoimg\temp\2fa8af078803491746235057c546c1b6.svg"');
```

Also as Barkermn01 has pointed out [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) needs a string input

Comment: its also not doing anything wid exec('java -version');