# PHP exec java on IIS 7

Tags: java, php, iis-7, exec

I am trying to exec a java jar file using php exec();

The command is

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\batik\batik-rasterizer.jar" -m image/png -d "C:/path/to/file/filename.png" -w 800 "C:/path/to/file/filename.svg"
```

When I run this command on the server using CMD.exe or Power Shell works fine but when I run it with PHP using exec() or system() or shell_exec() it will not execute returning a blank page

Comment: Does the IIS user account have access/execute permissions on the java.exe and containing directories?

Comment: @Marc ban Question its repeat of the last one we just tried to help

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154715/running-java-jar-from-php-exec-or-shell-exec-isnt-working-for-batik

Comment: Marc B: yes it has access/execute permissions for iis_usrs

Comment: I am not even getting a result when I run exec('java -version');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I got it figured out,

First the java jdk shouldn't be installed in the programs folder for some reason iis_iusrs doesn't have the permission to execute any files there.

Secondly the code should look like this

```
exec("C:\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java.exe -jar C:\\batik\\batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png -d "C:\\path\\to\\file\\filename.png" -w 800 "C:\\path\\to\\file\\filename.svg");
```