# jar file wont execute in php, gives me a blank page; jar does execute in cmd

Tags: java, php, maven, iis, jar

I have literally tried EVERYTHING and have spent the past 48 hours glued to my machine trying to figure this same problem out with no luck. We are running a IIS 6 Server / PHP 5.3.3 I have searched up and down thru the .ini file to make sure everything was turned to off or didn't have any effect(safe mode, etc.)  I uninstalled and reinstalled Java on the web server on a folder that isn't in the C:\Program Files folder(seen a example on stack to do this 
[PHP exec java on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155153/php-exec-java-on-iis-7)).

I can get the php file to execute the jar file through command prompt.

this is the code I have inside php.

exec('"C:\java\comp_java\jre\bin\java" -jar \\mywebserver\inetpub\wwwroot\Java\dist\houses.jar');
(triple backslashes before mywebserver and double backslashes everywhere else)

inside command prompt I simply type in:
1. php + spacebar
2. drag and drop the .php file and press enter

it works how I want it to. I have literally exhausted myself searching and don't know what else I could do. No output comes out the php page and my jar file doesn't get executed. the IIS manager on the web server has a dropdown with websites that my folder is included in and I have all the permissions on full blast. Im guessing that the IIS and exec() command in php don't gel together real well and that's the cause of the problem. I don't want to run apache since IIS is already setup. Let me save some grief and reiterate that I have browsed thru stack examples these past two days with no luck. As similar as my question i guarantee something is different, i just don't know what yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I figured out I can only get it to work using "Windows Integrated authentication" in IIS settings. Since im trying to use this function for client computers, Windows Integrated authentication isn't supported over http connections and is good for intranet use only, which almost defeats to purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the slashes...this worked for me. I created a file named `try.php` with content:

```
<?php 
exec("c:/dev/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java.exe -jar C:/dcevm-0.2-win.jar");
```

And it works OK

Comment: Same effect, a blank IE browser comes up and the jar file doesn't launch

Comment: Figured out I can launch it on the web server when I check "Integrated Windows Authentication" in the IIS settings; but on the other hand I cant call it through client side computers(Integrated Windows Authentication disables when running through http). any takers?